How to retrieve data from specific node related to another node by checking in Firebase-Real time Database?
Here is my firebase structure
Firebase Structure
When user makes an item favourite,its key will store under users ID along with category in the Favourite Node (for my easiness i stored category along with the key rather than storing boolean value)
My problem is, how to check for the id's of users favourite items and then retrieve the data from specific node of category relate to that ID's category.
i know this type of joining is not possible in No-Relational Databases like this, but is there any easy way of doing this kind of things like SQL querying while minimizing the billing cost and time, i know this can be done in nested listeners, but i am checking weather how this can be done easily with minimizing looping time and the billing cost, I'm open to suggestions regarding restructuring my firebase data structure.

What is the exact node that you want to check for existence?

Sure. Client-side joins with Firebase Realtime Database are actually quite fast and pretty cheap. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786 for more on that, and then post a minimal repro if you're having trouble making it work.

@AlexMamo node which I want to retrieve data depends on the category stored under the model id in the favourite node. there are a few more categories like animals.
